# How to write a parser and validator of an SPF record?

Tags: parsing, interpreter, lexer, spf

I'd like to try my hand at writing a parser, specifically I want to parse and validate an SPF record (https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7208). This is mostly a learning exercise so I'd like to build it from the bottom up without using any external tools like ANTLR.

An SPF record looks like this:

```
   v=spf1 a ip4:192.0.2.1 include:_spf.google.com ?exists:%{l1r+}.%{d} redirect=_spf.example.com -all
```

The RFC has a grammar specification: https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7208#page-46

There are several open-source implementations available, but most of them do not have a well-defined lexer/parser:

1. https://github.com/apache/james-jspf
2. https://github.com/sdgathman/pyspf
3. https://github.com/softvu/spf-parse/
4. https://github.com/Mika56/PHP-SPF-Check/
5. https://github.com/zaccone/spf
6. https://github.com/kbrw/mailibex

Actually, [5] does have a lexer and a parser but I'm not sure if the way they are implemented helps with the code architecture and maintainability.

I have no prior experience with a task like this and have some gaps in understanding how to approach it, so the questions I have are not so much about parsing an SPF-record as about building a parser in general:

1. Is it a good problem to solve using a lexer/parser or it's easier to use some custom parsing with string splitting and regular expressions (like [2],[3],[4])? [1] solves this by building a large regular expression with all the rules for mechanisms and modifiers combined and then goes over the match result group by group matching groups to the original rules - it is a modular approach but the implementation looks a little convoluted and it is not easy to understand where a part of an expression is actually processed.
2. If I do write a lexer what would be the tokens? Would `include` and `a` be tokens or a token should be something like `ID: [a-z]+`? Should `192.0.2.1` be an IP token and if so when should it be validated? What about macro like `%{l1r+}` and delimiters like `:` or `=`?
3. What would be the result of parsing? It seems that instead of an AST it would be better to have a list of objects like `[SpfVersion, AMechanism, IncludeMechanism, RedirectModifer]`.
4. What a parser would look like? Should it have rules like this that are tried one by one? :

```
   def matchIp4(): Ip4Mechanism {
     if(matchIp4Token() == null) return null
     if(matchSemicolonToken() == null ) return Ip4Mechanism()
     
     val  ip4 = matchIp4Literal()
     if(ip4 == null) throw InvalidSyntax(...)
     ...
     return Ip4Mechanism(ip4, ...)
   }
```

5. When would be an appropriate place for validations like validating a syntax of an SPF-macro or a structure of an ip6 address?

It's clear I have a huge gaps in my understanding on how to do this. Reading the Language Implementation Patterns book didn't help a lot - it is an easy read but I feel that examples there are too simplistic to actually show how a real parser/interpreter would be build. I also looked into more advanced sources like the Dragon book but I afraid I'll lose any motivation to implement this by the time I finish studying the book. Maybe there is a good hands-on guide on how to do this to get me started right now that doesn't require a year of reading first?

Thanks!

Comment: You may not find my comment particularly helpful; this is just my opinion. All of your questions are the right questions and in seeking to find reasonable answers yourself is where you will the exercise will pay the most dividends. You will, of course, need to do more reading and may even go down a few false trails and have to backtrack. So ask yourself how strong is your initial motivation to take this journey.

Comment: You're probably right. I read Principles of Compiler Design up to the chapter on parsing and it didn't help much - there is a mention of difficulties with parsing Fortran code but no descriptions on how those problems are usually solved.
The syntax of an SPF record seems to be lexer-hostile and a lexer needs context to determine a token type or sometimes even boundaries.
So the answer to my first question is no, it is easier to parse an SPF record by splitting and regex'ing.

Comment: The lexer/parser code would be small though. It did take me a lot of time to do a half-baked version but the lexing/parsing part is actually pretty compact and probably not very hard to write if you have some experience doing it.
By the way, I was surprised to see that although every book on compiler design after describing the basics recommends using a parser generator, a lot of well-known parsers (gcc, clang or even yaml parsers) are actually hand-written.

Comment: I don't know the specifics of the genesis of gcc. You say that it was hand-written. I believe that. But you say that it did not use a parser generator. *That* I find a little more surprising (or even difficult to believe). *Hand-written*, which is a fuzzy term, does not preclude the use of a parser generator of some sort whose primary purpose is to generate, for example, the LALR(1) parsing tables for some grammar. That is still only a small percentage of what comprises a C compiler.